# How to solve magento error

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

My Magento version is 1.7.0.2.

It was working fine till I tried to create a new store.I added new website and the site went all crezy.I am new with magento don't know what to do.[image: This is the error message]

This is the error message I am getting after changing local.xml.sample to local.xml

```
Error in file: "H:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\sql\catalog_setup\upgrade-1.6.0.0.9-1.6.0.0.10.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'catalog_product_entity_group_price' already exists

Trace:
#0 H:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(645):    Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 H:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.6.0.0.9', '1.6.0.0.14')
#2 H:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.6.0.0.9', '1.6.0.0.14')
#3 H:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 H:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 H:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 H:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 H:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

Please help me out..

Comment: Please post your error message as text so it can be found via search engines by others running into the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure you've got version 1.7.02? Because the upgrade script was executed. It's not a solution, but you can try to remove the file `upgrade-1.6.0.0.9-1.6.0.0.10.php` or comment out the lines ... ^^ If you have enough time it is better to correct this error ...

Comment: yes its version 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 3):

Megha, go to the database table "core_resource" and look for "catalog_setup" in code field than set the version and data_version field value as 1.6.0.0.14, I feel that you have issue with these values. Once you done with it than clear the cache and refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks for the idea..I kind of cheated to resolve this..I realized the issue is in database so I just deleted the old database and re installed it..All my records are gone but site is working fine now..:)

Comment: if you look into the table of your new database you will find the value as 1.6.0.0.14. Anyway you have found the other way to resolve it.

Comment: @RamSharma : it is not working for me. I have same issue